# Get the text of a treeview item using it's Id - Treeview Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit

I would like to get the display text of the treeview item `subdir3` when I double click. I know `'text'` is not correct as `print tree.set('subdir3')` prints a dictionary of columns and values and text is not part of that, but I can't find anything about it in the limited documentation I have found.

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

def OnDoubleClick(event):
    print tree.set('subdir3')['text']


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

tree["columns"]=("one","two")
tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
tree.heading("two", text="column B")

tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir3', text="sub dir 3", values=("3A"," 3B"))

tree.bind("<Double-1>", OnDoubleClick)


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Desired output:
    `sub dir 3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `identify` method to get the item under the cursor, and the `item` method to get information about that item:

```
def OnDoubleClick(event):
    item = tree.identify("item", event.x, event.y)
    print "you clicked on", tree.item(item)["text"]
```

Comment: I tried to make the example simple, but perhaps using a click event wasn't the way to go. I want always use `subdir3`, not the one that was clicked on.

Comment: @user2242044: ok, so just hard-code that in: `tree.item("subdir3")["text"]`