# How can I pass to the "open file" function the path of the directory I am clicking on in the tkinter tree in order to display it

Tags: python, tkinter

This code displays the directories and files however if I try to open a file by pressing the "open" button, I want it to open the highlighted path. I mean when I run this code, I get a perfect tree of what I have on my desktop as directories, if I expand one directory, a list of its files is perfectly listed. NOW I want to click on a file say a .txt file then I want to click on the OPEN button and I want it to actually open this file!

Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

def openfile():
    filedialog.askopenfilename()####I WANT IT TO OPEN WHATEVER I 

###HIGHLIGHT LATER IN THE TREE AFTER RUNNING 

def populate_tree(tree, node):
    if tree.set(node, "type") != 'directory':
        return

    path = tree.set(node, "fullpath")
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children(node))

    parent = tree.parent(node)
    special_dirs = [] if parent else glob.glob('.') + glob.glob('..')

    for p in special_dirs + os.listdir(path):
        ptype = None
        p = os.path.join(path, p).replace('\\', '/')
        if os.path.isdir(p): ptype = "directory"
        elif os.path.isfile(p): ptype = "file"

        fname = os.path.split(p)[1]
        id = tree.insert(node, "end", text=fname, values=[p, ptype])

        if ptype == 'directory':
            if fname not in ('.', '..'):
                tree.insert(id, 0, text="dummy")
                tree.item(id, text=fname)
        elif ptype == 'file':
            size = os.stat(p).st_size
            tree.set(id, "size", "%d bytes" % size)
#    button = ttk.Button(root, text="Open", command=openfile)  # <------
#    button.grid(column=1, row=1)

def populate_roots(tree):
    dir = os.path.abspath('.').replace('\\', '/')
    node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=dir, values=[dir, "directory"])
    populate_tree(tree, node)

def update_tree(event):
    tree = event.widget
    populate_tree(tree, tree.focus())

def change_dir(event):
    tree = event.widget
    node = tree.focus()
    if tree.parent(node):
        path = os.path.abspath(tree.set(node, "fullpath"))
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            os.chdir(path)
            tree.delete(tree.get_children(''))
            populate_roots(tree)


def autoscroll(sbar, first, last):
    """Hide and show scrollbar as needed."""
    first, last = float(first), float(last)
    if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
        sbar.grid_remove()
    else:
        sbar.grid()
    sbar.set(first, last)

root = tkinter.Tk()

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath", "type", "size"),
    displaycolumns="size", yscrollcommand=lambda f, l: autoscroll(vsb, f, l),
    xscrollcommand=lambda f, l:autoscroll(hsb, f, l))

vsb['command'] = tree.yview
hsb['command'] = tree.xview

tree.heading("#0", text="Directory Structure", anchor='w')
tree.heading("size", text="File Size", anchor='w')
tree.column("size", stretch=0, width=100)

populate_roots(tree)
tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', update_tree)
tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', change_dir)

 #Arrange the tree and its scrollbars in the toplevel: side="left", fill="both", expand=True
tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')
vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Open", command=openfile)  # <------
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I want it to open the file or path that I am highlighting in the browse mode. Thanks

Comment: You can provide a `directory` argument to askopenfilename to make it open the explorer window in that directory. Or are you asking "how do I get the current highlighted directory from my tree from within `openfile`?"? I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "open file". In Python, "open" usually refers to the `open()` function, which returns a `file` object that you can call read() and write() on. But in most other software, "open" means that the contents of a file will be made visible to the user in some way. Which of these meanings, if any, do you mean?

Comment: @MariamRakka: Please confirm. You want to open a file with highlighted data from your **own** `Treeview` widget. For this you **don't** need `filedialog.` as this is double work. Read [selecting-data-from-a-treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419515/selecting-data-from-a-treeview) and [get-the-text-of-a-treeview-item-using-its-id-treeview-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793795/get-the-text-of-a-treeview-item-using-its-id-treeview-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

Just import the `popen` method of the `os` lib. It opens the file with a path. In order to get the path of the chosen treeview you need to get the focus of the treeview and then get the item of the focus, which is a dictionary of information of the chosen item. to get the path you need to get the values and choose the first one (the path). Then you use the `popen` to open the file.

```
from os import popen    
def openfile():
    curItem = tree.focus()
    popen(tree.item(curItem)['values'][0])
```

Comment: Well, I added this function and I ran, clicked on a text file in the tree preview, then clicked open and this is what I keep getting: <os._wrap_close object at 0x115e8b5f8>

Comment: It seems the curItem is giving the address of the open button not the file I am highlighting...? I really don't know it is the first time I use Tkinter.

Comment: @MariamRakka: Show the output of `print(tree.item(curItem)['values'][0])`

Comment: @MariamRakka I've used your code and added my code, it worked for me just fine.